# how to add left and right padding between bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

here is my code

```
<div class="community_content">
                <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
   </div>
```

but i can'nt understand how i add spaces between columns
here is the image of the of layout which i want

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcSWD.jpg)

Comment: padding doesn't go between divs.... **margins** do!

Answer (score 3):

You can include another div inside each `.col-sm-3` div. Like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
   <div class="box">the content</div>
</div>
```

Then format this div as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You can use padding to gain that effect. Here you can see an example where the gray boxes are the .col-sm-3 and the black boxes are the div element inside the parent div. So without the borders, you will get the effect.

Link to Codepen: http://codepen.io/RasmusLauridsen/pen/wzLqXa

Like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-3"><div class="div">One</div></div>
```